# Pull to refresh VS Real-time VS Observable/Subscription pattern

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

*Statement 1:*

If we have a Real-time pattern(Firestore) then we don't need the `pull to refresh` features on the mobile app.

Note: I know the above statement is **correct**.

*Statement 2:*

Can we achieve the same thing using the `Observable/Subscription pattern` too? i.e. without `pull to refresh` feature on the mobile app.

**Note:** Here I meant (i.e. `Observable/Subscription` pattern) data is getting through Angular `http` call.

Comment: You always can do that with or without observable, it's socket push. Just like stackoverflow, you sometimes gets an update notification while you sit on a page.

Comment: This is not what I meant. Please see the **Note**. @FanCheung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP's feedback**

Can we achieve the same thing using the `Observable/Subscription pattern`? **No**. You cannot.

The below method is not recommended at all due to performance issues and etc.

**Original Answer**

If you want to use http call for this purpose 
you can just send request by a fix interval and see if there's any update on the server side, such stream can be something like below

```
interval(5000).pipe(
   // request for new information
   switchMap(()=>http.get(url)),
   tap(()=>// do your ui update)
).subscribe()
```

Comment: If I use observable in this way then it won't update the `myname` automatically if there is an `update on db`? `{{ myname | async }}`

Comment: is there reason you not use the firebase module which support firebase observable but want to use http call instead?

Comment: Actually, this is an R&D task where try to clarify a few things on `subscription` on angular `http` call. What do you think about the above `comment` i.e. `{{ myname | async }}`?

Comment: Using asynpipe that react to fire base stream is a natural choice. You can compose the stream and modify data coming from fire base to suit ur needs